# I need help in designing a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

[image]

I am working on  a hotel management system in asp.net and I have a problem with designing the database.

I have something like this:

1. two types of Guests :family and company
2. each type can have many members and every member has attributes
3. the reservation is made by a guest

I think I need to make 3 tables:

- **Guest:** `guest id` primary key, `Guest name`, `Member ID` foreign key
- **Members:** `Member ID` primary key, `Name`, `address`, ...
- **Reservation:** `Reservation ID` primary key, `guest ID` foreign key, ...

My problem is that I don't know how to make relation between tables.

For example the guest is company and he makes a reservation for 5 members,
but after a month he wants to make another reservation for 8 members.

What should I make so that I can make a reservation second time without being obligated to make another `guest ID`?

Comment: You need a [ReservationGuest] Table with ReservationID, GuestID as a compound primary key.

Comment: Why do the guests need to have an ID? Aren't the guests' names just an attribute of the member's reservation? If in the original reservation he spelled Peggy's name wrong, then corrects it, is that a new person or the same person? I would just wipe the names from the reservation and re-create them if he comes back and edits it...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the schema doesn't need to be much more complex than this, unless you also need to show where certain guests get their own room, etc. As I mentioned in my comment, I don't think there is anything that dictates that every guest must be a member, in which case I would just wipe out `ReservationGuests` and re-populate when the reservation gets updated. Who wants to write logic that tries to guess which of the original guests are actually still on the list?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Members
(
  MemberID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- ... name, address, etc.
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Reservations
(
  ReservationID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  MemberID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Members(MemberID),
  ... other attributes such as dates
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ReservationGuests
(
  ReservationID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Reservations(ReservationID),
  GuestName NVARCHAR(255),
  ... other guest attributes
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assuming that the guest has members.  It doesn't- as you mention, this week I might travel with my spouse, next week I might travel with the whole family, the week after that I might travel alone.  The **reservation** has members, and the set of members might be different for each reservation.  Hope that helps.

Comment: you are right so i should make something like this in Reservations table i shoud put a member id foreign key and make a table member with member id primary key.I put a image of how my database need to be.

Answer (score 0):

well u will need separate table for guests so for the 1st time they came to hotel u have to register that guest on your system. and as you said maybe he will come again after one month so just u have to search his SSN (Social Security Number). if he already register you don't have to register him again.

and your reservation table should be separate. and you should issue Reservation ID for each booking. so u can separately identify fields.

as example

A company came and resisted 1st time his registration number is "101"  and that time his Reservation ID is "555"

after one month he will come again. and your system have option that check whether he is already resisted or not. well after system notice he already resisted and just make new Reservation ID for new booking

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(
    Id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(256),
    Address VARCHAR(512),
    MemberTypeId INT  --FK to MemberType.Id
)

CREATE TABLE MemberType
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TypeDescription VARCHAR(128)
)

CREATE TABLE Reservation
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    MemberId INT --FK to Member.Id
)

CREATE TABLE ReservationList
(
    ReservationId INT, --FK to Reservation.Id
    MemberId INT --FK to Member.Id
    --Both of these values can act as a composite key
    --At minimum, they should be unique as a pair
)
```

The above schema is how I would create the database based on your description. The Reservation table merely acts as an overarching reservation, and can be made by the company member without having to actually include the company member in the reservation (company makes reservation, but only for its employees). Then, the ReservationList is the list of all the members that will be tied to each reservation.

Hopefully this helps :)